# Cannot select value in dropdown box (inline edit)

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

What is wrong with this code and i cannot select the value in the dropdown box when editing inline?

I've done this using textbox only but in this case I wanted to use a dropdown option and select its value...

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" id="tblMain" class="edit">
   <tr>
       <td>Edit this:</td>
       <td class="edit shift<?php echo " ".$row['ctrID']?>"><?=$row['shift']?></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the js:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){       

    $('td.edit').click(function(){  
                $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                $(this).addClass('ajax');

               // this is the part i am having a trouble with: 

                $(this).html('<select id="editbox" size="'+$(this).text().length+'"><?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($editShift)){ ?><option value="' + $(this).text() + '"><?=$row['shiftCode']?></option><?php } ?></select>');
                $('#editbox').focus();
    });

    $('#editbox').live('blur',function(){
                 $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                 $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    });
});

$('td.edit').keydown(function(event){
            arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
            if(event.which == 13)
                    { 
            $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "get.php",
            data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rownum="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1],
            success: function(data){
                $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                                }});
                    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time on clicking the td having class edit,

the dropdown markup  is replacing the td 
by the below line

```
$(this).html('<select id="editbox">...</select>');
```

so u can check, if select dropdown already inserted inside the td..then skip the inserting the markup

like

```
 if($(this).find("#editbox").size() == 0)
           {

           // drop down markup will come here

           }
```